# What exceptions can be raised by HttpClient?

Tags: ruby

In the ruby 'net/http' standard library, what exceptions can be raised by `Net::Http` class when using the `new` method?

Looking at the documentation [here](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.1/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html) it's unclear what exceptions can be raised by that method. Even toggling "show source", and tracing the `new` method back to the `start` method and looking at its source, I don't see a clear indication of possible exceptions that could be raised.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Base class for `Net::Http` exceptions is `Net::HTTPExceptions`
We can look up its descendants like was described in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2393697/look-up-all-descendants-of-a-class-in-ruby).

```
require 'net/http'

puts ObjectSpace.each_object(Class).select { |x| x < Net::HTTPExceptions }
```

It outputs 4 class names:

```
Net::HTTPFatalError
Net::HTTPServerException
Net::HTTPRetriableError
Net::HTTPError
```

There are also some class names for compatibility, like

```
# for compatibility
Net::HTTPClientException = Net::HTTPServerException
```

Source file can be viewed in ruby [repository](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/c5eb24349a4535948514fe765c3ddb0628d81004/lib/net/http/exceptions.rb) on in local file (change Ruby version to yours)

```
C:\Ruby26-x64\lib\ruby\2.6.0\net\http\exceptions.rb
```

Comment: How do you know that is the base class for Net::Http exceptions? Where is this documented?

Comment: @AaronThomas https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.1/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTPExceptions.html 
It also stated in the source file (check last link in my answer). Basically that file (`exceptions.rb`) can answer your question without any additional actions.